# VueJS get url parameter with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a page (example.com/administration/product/add/1)

I want to get the last url parameter (1) with vue js.

My laravel route:

```
Route::get('product/add/{company?}', function ()
{
    return view('page.administration.admin.product.create');
})->name('Admin.Dashboard.Product.Create');
```

My attempt: 
this.$route.params.company but i get an error that $route is not defined.

Any tips?

Comment: In JS, `'example.com/administration/product/add/1'.split('/').pop()` would give you `1`

Comment: please show us your vuejs code

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Yor are calling for route: `administration/product/add/1` which is not defined in your route. please post your full **route** file.